# Guzzle HTTP send file stream throws error- "json_encode error: Type is not supported"

Tags: rest, api, curl, laravel-5, guzzle

I am using Guzzle client in my Laravel application to send a request to API endpoint along with a file. I am achieving this by creating a multipart data as follow-

```
$rid = $this->wsl->curlWSl('POST', '/throttle', [], [
            'verify' => false,
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name'     => 'csv',
                    'contents' => fopen($dest, 'rb')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'contents' => $request->input('name')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'contents' => $request->input('description')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'header',
                    'contents' => '1'
                ]
            ]
]);
```

The curlWSL method I have defined as given below -

```
public function curlWSl(string $method, string $path, Array $headers = [], Array $data = null, Array $options = [])
    {
        $endPoint = $this->getUri() . $path;

        if (!empty($headers)) {
            $options['headers'] = $headers;
        }

        if ($method == 'GET' && $data) {
            $endPoint .= http_build_query($data);
        }
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            $options['json'] = $data;
        }

        try {
            $response = $this->getClient()->request(
                $method,
                $endPoint,
                $options
            );
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return ['statusCode'=>$ex->getCode(), 'errorMsg' => $ex->getMessage()];
        }

        return json_decode($response->getBody()) ?? (string)$response->getBody();
    }
```

Doing this, throws me an exception -

```
InvalidArgumentException {#296 ▼
  #message: "json_encode error: Type is not supported"
  #code: 0
  #file: "/var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/functions.php"
  #line: 327
  trace: {▶}
}
```

I am sure, this is because of fopen file stream because when I remove that, my request is received at the endpoint.

I am also looking for some help on how can I validate the request data at the API endpoint using **laravel validators**.

Your help is much appreciated.

**Note: I am much looking to pass the file object and not only the file data, which I am able to do with file_get_contents.**

Comment: What I see is your wrapper is asking if method is "POST" and setting up a json => data. But actually, what Guzzle expects there is the whole third parameter in the request method, not setting up just an only "json" key. Also, looks like you are double wrapping your Guzzle implementation. Looks like too much of a hassle.

Comment: @MarkSkayff, thanks for suggesting, you are right, Guzzle don't process too many parameters, if it get `json=>data` available then it ignores the multipart data from the request. So, I had to remove `json=>data` from the options data to make things working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it fixed.
The Guzzle don't process too many parameters to send as in request to the endpoint. As we are setting up `$options['json'] = $data` and this considers the data in json format which is actually not. So, I had to turn it to multipart instead of json to make things working. I had to modify the call as below -

```
$rid = $this->wsl->curlWSl('POST', '/throttle', [], [
                [
                    'name'     => 'csv',
                    'contents' => fopen($dest, 'rb')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'name',
                    'contents' => $request->input('name')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'description',
                    'contents' => $request->input('description')
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'header',
                    'contents' => '1'
                ]
]);
```

And in the method **curlWSL**, I modified the code as to accept the data as multipart-

```
public function curlWSl(string $method, string $path, Array $headers = [], Array $data = null, Array $options = [])
    {
        $endPoint = $this->getUri() . $path;

        if (!empty($headers)) {
            $options['headers'] = $headers;
        }

        if ($method == 'GET' && $data) {
            $endPoint .= http_build_query($data);
        }
        if ($method == 'POST') {
            $options['multipart'] = $data;
        }

        try {
            $response = $this->getClient()->request(
                $method,
                $endPoint,
                $options
            );
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return ['statusCode'=>$ex->getCode(), 'errorMsg' => $ex->getMessage()];
        }

        return json_decode($response->getBody()) ?? (string)$response->getBody();
    }
```

Comment: Could you let me know, where these function *curlWSL* is written, I means the path, where I need to update?